# Find a Character in a Search String of a file

Tags: python

```
x = 'redo.txt'
def find(x):
    with open(x, 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            print(line[0].find("#"))
find(x)
```

I want to create a function that detemine whether a line in a file contain hastage. If it exist, it returns the index of the first occurrence of that character in the search string. If it doesnt exist, it returns -1. Where did I messed up on this coding?

Comment: Your function always returns `None` for starters. Also, why are you doing `line[0]`? That only searches *the first character in the line*.

Comment: How can I change it to return what I want?

Comment: Don't do `line[0]`. You should print `line` so you can see it and understand what it is you are dealing with. The question is, *why* did you do `line[0]`. What was your reasoning for that? Furthermore, as already mentioned, you are not returning anything in your function, you have to actually *return* something when your operation is finished. You probably want to check if your find actually worked and if it did, return early so you don't exhaust through your loop for no reason. I think you should be good from here.